# Swift 4: Getting first two digits in float

Tags: ios, swift

i am trying to get the first two digits in a float that changes continuously, i tried `%.05f`,`%.5f` `%.3f`, but it didn't work,

the code i used

```
 let str = NSString(format: "%.01f", Float(totalBytesWritten))
```

the value (float) i created looks something like this `294525.0`, but i want to get the first two digits, something like  `29`

Thanks

Comment: so for 123456.789 and 1234 you want in both cases to just get 123? And what about 1.23?

Comment: @luk2302, can you help me, i've updated my question, yeah 1.23 is fine and it could do

Comment: Please update your question with actual relevant code. Then clearly show exact input and exact desired output.

Comment: @rmaddy, bugem, updated mate

Comment: But you didn't provide clear examples of real input and desired output. Your requirement is still very unclear.

Comment: looks like what you need is to divide the bytes written by the expected content length

Comment: @rmaddy, what are you talking about mate? i have a float the value of it is `294525.0` and trying to get `29`, means first two digits ,

Comment: this is not a percentage. You should read my comment

Comment: "looks like what you need is to divide the bytes written by the expected content length" can you make this as an answer?

Comment: It's clear to you maybe. What is the `%` in your number? Is `%294525.0` a `String`? Again, clearly explain what you have and what you want. On the surface your question is too trivial since you simply want the leading 3 characters of a string. But if it were really that simple you wouldn't have posted the question.

Comment: @rmaddy, i missed that, i just copied the float value, sorry, i've removed the percentage

Comment: You should make your goal clear. Are you trying to display the percentage of the data being dowloaded to the user?

Comment: @LeoDabus, exactly

Comment: So you need to divide `totalBytesWritten` by `totalBytesExpectedToWrite` and display the resulting percentage

Comment: @LeoDabus, right. i also have the `totalBytesExpectedToWrite`, but tried to ask the question differently

Comment: So if are you trying to display a value from 0 to 100 you would need to multiply the result by 100. And dont forget to convert the `Int64` to `Double` before doing your math

Comment: @LeoDabus, since i am new to swift, your help is highly appreciated

Comment: @SarmandAmer edit your question, update it accordingly to the comments and make it clear to demonstrate what is your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to convert the number of bytes writen to display to the user as the download percentage completed, you would need first to convert the `totalBytesWritten` from Int64 to Double as well as the `totalBytesExpectedToWrite`. Then you divide the written by the expected to write and multiply the result by 100:

```
let percentageCompleted = (Double(totalBytesWritten)/Double(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)) * 100 
let percentageToDisplay = String(format: "%.0f%%", percentageCompleted)
```

Comment: I'm still waiting for the question to be clarified because this answer (while clearly correct) has nothing to do with getting the first two digits of a floating point number. The question should be asking how to display the currently downloaded bytes as a percentage.